# How to load large data set from calling a procedure (Table Input) to destination table efficiently through Pentaho kettle?

Tags: mysql, loops, pentaho-data-integration

I am planning to split the number of rows from procedure and then load them into a table, and using loop, it continues to load certain rows to table.

I am unsure of the way to do it.

My Process: Table Input (calling a procedure - returns 900 million records) -> Data conversion -> Insert / update step (incremental loading to a target table).

Now I have to retrieve few records (say 1 million at a time) from procedure, based on some field in the procedure,  then load them into table. This has to be iterated until end of the rows from procedure.

Kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a problem with this, other than the time it takes to process that many rows.  PDI (Spoon/Kettle) works with ***streams***, not "***data sets***" like in SQL, and rows are processed as soon as they are received.  Because of this, PDI will likely never have to deal with all 900 million rows at once, and you will not have to wait for all of them to be returned from SQL before it starts processing.

The `Table output` step has a `Commit size` value to control how many records are sent to your target table in one ***transaction***.  The trick is to balance the amount of time it takes to start new connections with the time it takes to process a large number of rows in one transaction.  I run values from 200 to 5000, depending my need and system's ability, but you may be able to go higher than that.

It sounds like your bigger problem will be returning that many rows from a Stored Procedure.  Using an SP instead of a `SELECT` or `VIEW` means you will have to find ways to keep memory pressure low.

I have a few multi-million row tables, and I create `TEMP` tables (non-table variables) to store data while processing, using a single `SELECT * FROM temp..table` at the end of the SP.  This streams the data from the server as expected and uses the minimum amount of memory.